# Call 2 functions in one 'toggle' button

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button that needs to call 2 functions. When the user clicks the button it should call the first function, then when the user clicks the same button it should call the second function. I would also like the text in the button to change based on the function that is called.
Here is my code

```
  firstFunction() {
      ...
  }

  secondFunction() {
      ...
  }

  <button mat-flat-button  (click)="" color="accent">First function called</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `toggle` function to switch beetween the two functions like this:

```
let toogled: boolean;
firstFuntion(){}  
secondFuntion(){}
public toggle(): boolean {

   return this.toggled ? this.firstFuntion() : this.secondFuntion();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this strategy;

```
 <button mat-flat-button  (click)="toggleButton()" color="accent">First function called</button>
```

And toggleButton():

```
toggleButton() {
  if(!this.isToggled){
    firstFunction();
  }else{
    secondFunction();
  }
  this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
}
```

You have to declare `isToggled` variable and initialize it to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="button"
       (click)="isFirstClick?first():second()"
       value="click me">
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  isFirstClick = true;
  first() {
    this.isFirstClick = !this.isFirstClick;
    console.log('first');
  }

  second() {
    this.isFirstClick = !this.isFirstClick;
    console.log('second');
  }
```